# Show that $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ and $x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+5$ cannot be a square when $x\neq3$ and $x\neq2$ respectively.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

As the title says, I need help showing that $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ and $x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+5$  cannot be a square when $x\neq3$  and $x\neq2$  respectively, where $x$ is a natural number.

In order to do this, I have to use the fact that if $x$ is any natural number >1, any natural number $n\geq x$ can be represented uniquely in the form

$n=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+...+c_mx^m$,

where $0\leq c_i \leq x-1$ for $i=0,1,2,...,m-1$  and
$0< c_m \leq x-1$.

Answer (score 4):

If $x > 3$ and $n = x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is a square then $4n$ is also a square.  However

$$ \begin{eqnarray}4(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1) &=& (2x^2 + x)^2 + 3x^2 + 4x+4 \\ &=& (2x^2+x+1)^2 - (x+1)(x-3) \end{eqnarray}$$

which shows that

$$(2x^2 + x)^2 < 4n < (2x^2+x+1)^2.$$

Since $4n$ is between two consecutive squares it cannot be a square itself.  In the same way

$$ \begin{eqnarray}x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+5 &=& (x^2 + x)^2 + x^2 + 2x+5 \\ &=& (x^2+x+1)^2 - (x+2)(x-2) \end{eqnarray}$$

which shows that $x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+5$ is not a square when $x>2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: IF either of these numbers were squares, then you could express them as $N^2$, where $N$ is some number. By what you know, you can write $N=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\ldots+c_mx^m$ uniquely. Notice that $N$ uses at most three powers of $x$: $N=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2$, since when you square it you need an $x^4$ to appear as the highest power. Now square $N$ out and show you can't have nonnegative $c_i$ which give you the coefficients of your numbers. For example, for $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$, you immediately get $c^2_0\equiv 1\pmod{x}$.

Comment: I don't think $c_0=1$ necessarily. Write $11=1*3^2+2*3^0$ so that $c_0=2$, then $11^2=121=3^4+3^3+3^2+3+1$. So wouldn't the condition only be $c_0^2\equiv 1 mod x$.

Comment: @NLH thanks for the correction.